# Relationships Not Passing from SQL Server to Linq to Entity Model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a Linq to Entity model from my SQL Server Database and most of the relationships are not being passed. There are four relationships are being passed which is really weird because I made all the relationships the same way. I used the Diagram in SQL Server to create all of the relationships by dragging and dropping the foreign keys to the primary key table.

I have tried to look at the relationships that are being passed to see if there is any difference, but I was unable to find any. I even deleted and made a new relationship with no luck.

This database does work with a Linq To SQL data model perfectly, so I do not believe it is an issue with the database design, but I could be wrong.

Everything looks perfect in the SQL Diagram View and even the Database diagram that is in the Server Explorer in VS 2010, but the L2E model does not have the relationships.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you update your entities model from database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every relationship in SQL, make sure that the referenced table has a Primary Key.

Let's consider the following example: we have the `Invoice` and `Customer` tables. `Invoice` has a column called `CustomerId` that references the `Id` column in the `Customer` table.

In this scenario, the `Customer` table should have a primary key set on `Id` in order for Entity Framework to properly detect the relationship.

**Note:** If you discover such a case (tables without Primary Keys) it might be best to re-create the tables from scratch (generate creation scripts, alter the scrips to include primary keys, run the scripts) and then try to update the EF model.